# How to reset a Angular4's FormGroup to its original state?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular4 more specific reactive forms. I was running the Heroes demo, and I got stuck on something.

On this **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DLohBaYGUF155eUS49N0?p=preview)** we have to pick a superhero, and it will show hero's addresses. I added a reset button for each address, but when I click to reset an address, it resets everything.

In the example we have:

```
 createForm() { //Set up form and array of addresses
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      secretLairs: this.fb.array([]),
      power: '',
      sidekick: ''
    });
  }

  //Function to revert changes
  revert() { this.ngOnChanges(); }

  //This function will set the name from original object
  ngOnChanges() { 
    this.heroForm.reset({
      name: this.hero.name
    });

    //It will reload the form array with original values
    this.setAddresses(this.hero.addresses);
  }

  //Create new formgroups and add to formArray
  setAddresses(addresses: Address[]) {
    const addressFGs = addresses.map(address => this.fb.group(address));
    const addressFormArray = this.fb.array(addressFGs);
    this.heroForm.setControl('secretLairs', addressFormArray);
  }
```

This is ok, it works, but it will reset the entire form. For instance, Whirlwind has two addresses. I added a new address, and after that, I make a change to the first address. I make a mistake and want to get the original values, I click on the reset button, and it will remove my new address, and it will reset all data on the form.

How can I reset per address and not the entire form?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling a reset on changes? I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. How about a user-story like example? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I apologize if it missed something. I want to cancel the changes I made and load the previous values. For instance, it loads the first address and I start typing something there. When I click reset, it will show the original values for that specific address and not for the entire form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value` or `getRawValue()` to read the values after initialization.

After `reset()` you can then set the initial values back by using `setValue()` with the previously read values.

See also

- https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup
- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#populate-the-form-model-with-setvalue-and-patchvalue

Comment: I was thinking that I would be able to do that by item in array but it seems we do need to rebind the entire FormGroup right?

Comment: From what I have seen, you can either use `reset` and pass in all of the original data ... or you can use `setValue` or `patchValue`. Also ... I understand that `reset` does *not* currently create the correct number of FormArray elements on a reset. There is an issue for this posted in the Angular github repo. If you really only want to reset one value, then `patchValue` may be what you want.

Comment: And if you are interested, I have an example app using reactive forms here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms (in the APM folder). It uses `patchValue` to update the data on the form each time the user selects a new item to edit. You can use a similar technique to reset.

Comment: Does `setValue` reset control status? This is what I thought `reset` is still required for.